# Problem with Player not centering on lane if moving too quickly in opposite direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a previous question I had a problem with [Getting Precise Positioning of Rigidbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637325/can-not-get-precise-positioning-of-rigidbody-in-unity3d/64647992?noredirect=1#comment114344293_64647992). That problem being solved creates another problem.

If the user repeatedly taps a key to move in the opposite direction too quickly, the player can overshoot the center of the lane. Each lane is 1 unit wide, and the current code moves the player left/right exactly 1 unit each time a key is pressed.

How can I ensure that the player will always go to the center of the lane, no matter where they are in the move cycle?

This is the Player_Movement code:

```
public float mSpeed;


private Rigidbody rb;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //For Moving Left
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        StartCoroutine(MoveToPosition(rb.transform, new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), mSpeed));

    //For Moving Right
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        StartCoroutine(MoveToPosition(rb.transform, new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), mSpeed));

    Debug.Log(transform.position);
}

public IEnumerator MoveToPosition(Transform transform, Vector3 position, float timeToMove)
{
    var currentPos = transform.position;
    var t = 0f;
    while (t < 1)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, position, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Someone mentioned using a cooldown timer. Not letting the user move again until the timer reaches zero. But I need the player to be able to reverse his direction if they overshoot the desired lane. The obstacles will be coming at the player faster and faster as the game progresses, and the players sideways movement speed increases relative to the speed of the obstacles.

Since the gameplay gets pretty frantic, I'd like the player to be able to correct their position on the fly and not have to wait for a cooldown timer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from your coroutine.
If you repeat the same key before than the first coroutine is completed (in case of your speed), they will going to have two different coroutine which modify the position of your transform.

For solve that problem you can:

1. Prohibited to move until the position is not reached.
2. Move your coroutine inside your Update function.

1:
You can have a boolean (canMove for example) in your class, assign false to it when MoveToPosition is called, and then assign true to it before quit the MoveToPosition function. Don't forget to check your variable in conditions while check if keys are down.

2:
You can store a Vector3 (finalPos for example) in your class, and increment/decrement his x value when keys are down. After conditions, you just need to move your transform with the finalPos:

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, finalPos, Time.deltaTime * mSpeed);
```